# Google AdWords Conversion Tracking on a form send

Tags: javascript, onclick, google-ads-api, ajaxform

Good day,
I'm trying to configure the AdWords conversion code for my website and I can't find any of the information I'm looking for in Google documentation. Ultimatly, I want to track a onClick event on the submit input of the form.

I want to know what should I include in my onClick event, since the send button doesn't lead to another page, but have an AJAX loading?

My AdWords tracking code is :

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
   /* <![CDATA[ */
    goog_snippet_vars = function() {
      var w = window;
      w.google_conversion_id = 12345678;
      w.google_conversion_label = "abcDeFGHIJklmN0PQ";
      w.google_remarketing_only = false;
    }
    // DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW.
    goog_report_conversion = function(url) {
      goog_snippet_vars();
      window.google_conversion_format = "3";
      window.google_is_call = true;
      var opt = new Object();
      opt.onload_callback = function() {
      if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
        window.location = url;
      }
    }
    var conv_handler = window['google_trackConversion'];
    if (typeof(conv_handler) == 'function') {
      conv_handler(opt);
    }
 }
   /* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ultimately, I was looking for the conversion to be saved only if the form is sucessfully sent (After Javascript validation). I could not use the onClick on the button, because it would save the conversion even if the form has not submited due to an invalid value in a field.

The easiest way to do so, was to add this in jQuery :

```
$('#contactform').submit(function(e){
    if( $( this ).valid() ) {
        goog_report_conversion ('http://example.com/your-link') // Change for your page link.
        alert("Conversion!"); // Confirmation that the conversion has been sent. Remove after testing. 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's too late, but for the future generations. There is a built-in way for AdWords to do this.
It is described [in this article](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6331304).

In brief you would need to change setting in AdWords it would generate you async tag, which you load with the DOM, and activate with onClick handler.

---

Example:

```
<a onclick="goog_report_conversion ('http://example.com/your-link')"
href="http://example.com/your-link">Download now!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load de  of the noscript version.

So, in you onClick event, append the img to some element on the page and it will load it and will count the conversion.